# Can't fix Error: PL/SQL Statement ignored

Tags: sql, oracle

I've just started working with Triggers. While trying to compile the next code fragment errors are listed in the log, like so: "Error(2,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored" and "Error(2,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option".
I don't understand the problem. Can anybody help?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONT_VIG
BEFORE INSERT ON CONTRACTS
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (OLD.CLIENTID = NEW.CLIENTID AND OLD.ENDDATE > NEW.STARTDATE)

BEGIN
SET (OLD.enddate = :NEW.startdate-1);    
END;
```

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW` means for each row inserted - not for each row that exists in the table pre-insert.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm lots of examples provided in the docs

Comment: [Is this for the same assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43483253/266304)

Comment: First explain what are you trying to do - we cannot really comment on a code if we have no idea what are the requirements.

Comment: Where in the [PL/SQL manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00205) did you find the `SET` to assign values?

Answer (score 0):

> look this [this-oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm) and [this-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37138551/1332870)

### try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER hr.salary_check
      BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF salary, job_id ON hr.employees
      FOR EACH ROW
         WHEN (new.job_id <> 'AD_VP')
      pl/sql_block
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change OLD value...

replace

```
SET (OLD.enddate = :NEW.startdate-1);
```

with for example :

```
:NEW.startdate := sysdate ;
```

(I removed SET because I don't see the usefulness)

Comment: Removing SET has nothing to do with "usefulness" - it's plain wrong

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name : yes